# firebase_core in yaml not found

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Created brand new flutter project, no changes except
Added to yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "0.2.3"
```

After "packages get" the rebuild project gives error in GeneratedPluginRegistrant

```
**Error:(4, 40) java: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core does not exist
Error:(14, 5) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable FirebaseCorePlugin
  location: class io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
Information:javac 1.8.0_131 was used to compile java sources
Information:5/30/2018 7:18 AM - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 2 s 101 ms**
```

Flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.48], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.23.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)
```

Comment: I did the same on a Mac but do not get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core does not exist
This is a java classpath error. Just add to classpath

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `^` symbol in version declaration. The correct way would be,

***`firebase_core: "^0.2.3"`***

Comment: Are you able to create and run any sample flutter projects?

Comment: When I run I see in console Note: C:\flutter_windows_v0.3.2-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.2.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.